# Laplacian in spherica coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, spherical-coordinates, laplacian, singularity

I am solving the Laplacian in spherical coordinates using the Method of Lines and in the textbook I am studying, it is indicated that the Laplacian term:

$$\frac{1}{r^2}\bigg(\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\dfrac{\partial U}{\partial \theta}\bigg)$$

is singular at $r=0$ and at $\theta = 0$ and at $\theta=\pi/2$.

I definitively agree at $r=0$ and $\theta=0$, but I cannot agree with the singularity at $\theta = \pi/2$.

Can someone please confirm that my statement is correct. Otherwise, kindly explain why the term is singular at $\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: Would it be possible that this is a typo and the singularity is supposed to be at $\theta = \pi$? If you point out which textbook this claim comes from, we might be able to help you figure this out from context.

Comment: Thanks Elliot for your response. I have considered this but the author of the book is an expert in the area and I need to make sure this was a typo. The book in question is: A Compendium of Partial Differential Equation Models:Method of Lines Analysis with Matlab, William E. Schiesser and Graham W. Griffiths, 2009. Chapter 14, pages 377-378.

Comment: The author mentioned that the singularity comes from the $\sin\theta$ in the denominator, which is zero if $\theta = 0$ or $\pi$, but clearly not when $\theta = \pi/2$. Thus I'm inclined to think that the original claim is an error.

Comment: I also suspect some of the code included in the text hasn't been tested (which also makes it more likely that the claim about singularity was in error), because the lines discussed in point 8 on page 378 seems to contain an error too. In the second uncommented line, instead of `cos(j)/sin(j)`, it should probably be `cos(th(j))/sin(th(j))`, since `j` is an integer index that runs from `1` to `nth`, and it doesn't make much sense to evaluate sine and cosine directly on it.  Compare point 2 on page 364 where trigonometric functions are evaluated, for example.

Comment: It is possible that the author intended to highlight the fact that functions defined in spherical coordinates require extra care at the endpoints of their domains (for example when $\theta = 0, \pi$), but got confused because of the reduction of the domain to $\theta \in [0, \pi/2]$ using symmetry (mentioned at the end of point 1 on page 364).

Comment: Thanks Elliot for all the great and detailed explanation and I 100% agree with you. I will mark the question as solved and also thanks for the comments about the code. Really much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter pointed out, I believe you mean there is a singularity at $\theta = \pi$. Spherical coordinates are not differentiable at the poles $\theta=0$ and $\theta =\pi$ just as polar coordinates are not differentiable at $\theta=0$. This is due to the fact that the coordinate transformation does not form a bijection over the "polar" points. Consider a fixed point in spherical coordinates $p = (r,\theta,\varphi) = (R,\pi,\varphi) $. The coordinate $\varphi$ can be any number on $[0,2\pi)$ and still represent the same point in $(x,y,z)$ space.

The moral is that since we can't have a bijection, we can't have an invertible Jacobian transformation and thus we can't describe vectors (and therefore derivatives) at those points.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I quote the following line: "except that we still need to consider
the singularity for θ = 0, π/2 due to the 1/ sin θ term.", which I do not understand for the case θ = π/2.

Comment: @JulioGonzalez-Saenz I would agree with Elliot Yu that this is a typo or oversight from the author. Without reading more from the chapter, this is my best guess.

Comment: Correct. I think this was a typo and the author just missed this part as explained by Elliot.